# Why these diodes on AC transformer?

Tags: diodes

I’m repairing an old jukebox. I don’t understand why there is a diode that is soldered in reverse. Is there more voltage on the cathode than the anode? How does it work?

[image]

Comment: I forgot that that the transformer was giving 40 A, my bad  thanks for the reminder

Answer (score 11):

The referred portion of the circuit has been redrawn.

[image]

It's a conventional full-wave rectifier circuit that uses a centre-tapped transformer.

The diodes are oriented to obtain a negative output voltage with respect to the centre tap.

Answer (score 6):

They face the opposite way to create a negative voltage with respect to the "40" network. That is a negative voltage supply.

Comment: Ah ok, so if i check at mid point, i should get -40 V ? The diode is a 1N4007 ? So it uses reverse voltage to enable a low current (1uA) as i understand ?

Comment: @Anthox you understood it wrongly. Transformer's output is alternative current. So, it is not opposite or direct, it is just negative pole of voltage relative to 40V point.

Answer (score 3):

There is what looks like an underline character before the "40 V", so that might be confirmation that that node is indeed -40 V with respect to something.  But what?

The "40 V" transformer tap connects to two fuses, plus there is a net segment going outside the image.  Also, the transformer output marked "00 V" does not go to a GND symbol.  Without more of the schematic, it is hard to say what the -40 V is referred to.